# Matrix breaks Field Options on 2.8?

Tags: matrix, control-panel, 2.8

I'm installing my first 2.8 on a local machine, and noticed that the Field Options aren't showing up.

I retraced the steps and it turns out installing latest version of Matrix (2.5.10) breaks Field Options (i.e., FO stops showing up.)

Only CP related add-on I have is NSM's Override.css.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?

Comment: The error I was getting was `Uncaught TypeError: Object 153 has no method 'replace'`. It's not the error described in the support post Brandon linked below, but the patch provided does fix this for me.

Comment: If like me you got your theme path wrong it will produce the same problem. Just thought I'd add this in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s a Javascript bug in EE 2.8.0 that breaks the field settings page and other areas of the CP when certain add-ons are installed, including Matrix. It’ll be fixed in 2.8.1, and EllisLab has posted a patch file here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20165

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up here Brandon. The fix worked perfectly.